# making UIPinchGestureRecognizer and UIRotationGestureRecognizer working together

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I try to scale and rotate UIImageView using gestures. I've seen couple of examples on the Internet and I have implemented it, but it doesn't work together.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
   // imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"spotItInLondonIcon.png"];
    [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imgView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [imgView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinch:)];
    [imgView addGestureRecognizer:pinch];
    pinch.delegate = self;

    UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotate = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotation:)];
    [imgView addGestureRecognizer:rotate];
    rotate.delegate = self;
}
-(void)pinch: (UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    CGFloat scale = sender.scale;
    imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(imgView.transform, scale, scale);
    sender.scale = 1.0;
    NSLog(@"pinch executed");
}
-(void)rotation: (UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)rotationDetected
{
    CGFloat angle = rotationDetected.rotation;
    imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(imgView.transform, angle);
    rotationDetected.rotation = 0.0;
    NSLog(@"rotation executed");
}
```

then I added delegate to the .h file and method to app delegate.m but still only one gesture at the time works.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

can someone help me?

Comment: Is it always the same recognizer that works? Have you checked that they both work separately? i.e. only adding of them.

Comment: if i will start pinching then it will scale the image but i cannot pinch and rotate at the same time. If i will start rotating and then try to pinch at the same time then again only rotation works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

method to app delegate.m??you have to add the method in the class you are adding gesture , in your case, viewcontroller.m

```
    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

this method in viewcontroller.m not in appdelegate.m

Comment: that's the solution! I don't know, the method looks like it should be in the appDelegate but now I know I was my bad. Thank you for the answer.